# Why does adding an else statement slow my code so much?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, optimization

I feel like there is perhaps an obvious answer. When I'm running this code:

```
function searchQuery() {
  var compiledParticipantsSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Participants');
  var participantsSheetLr = compiledParticipantsSheet.getLastRow();
  var participantsSheetLc = compiledParticipantsSheet.getLastColumn();
  var querySheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Query');
  var querySheetLr = querySheet.getLastRow();
  var querySheetLc = querySheet.getLastColumn();
  var data = querySheet.getRange(3, 1, querySheetLr, querySheetLc).getValues();
  for (j = 2; j <= participantsSheetLr; ++j) {
    var val = compiledParticipantsSheet.getRange(j, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
    console.log('Searching Query sheet for row ' + j + ' -- ' + val)
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
      if (data[i][4] == val) {
        var foundData = (data[i][20]);
        console.log('------ Found email in query row ' + (i + 3) + ' = ' + foundData);
        compiledParticipantsSheet.getRange(j, 11, 1, 1).setValue(foundData);
      }else{
       compiledParticipantsSheet.getRange(j, 11, 1, 1).setValue('Participant not found');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It runs painfully slow, but if I remove the one else statement at the end it runs super fast! Is that reasonable? Am I missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: You should rewrite your code and get both column 2 and 11 all at one time in and array and at the end you can populate column eleven all at one time with a setvalues().  Your entire code will run much faster.

Comment: First, whereas before only a subset of rows were affected by `setValue()`.  Now all rows are affected so there may be a considerable number of `setValue()` calls.  Secondly, although Google App Script tries to cache `getValue()/setValue()` calls to reduce the total number of calls to the server, the introduction of the `else` may have thrown off the cache optimization resulting in a significant hit on performance.  I would follow @Cooper and `getValues()`, process the results in the local array and when all loops are done `setValues()`.